# get distance with nearFilter in loopback

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I am searching using mongodb connector with the query `location: {near: here, maxDistance:radius, unit:'meters'}`. This does return the correct documents, however I can't figure out how to return the distance matched for each document. Any ideas?

Comment: GeoPoint has a distanceTo method, also a static distanceBetween: http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#geopoint

Comment: @user3802077 but does that mean I have to manually go through each fetched record and calculate the distance and push back to the resultset, especially when mongodb is supposed to provide that by default? Sounds a bit counter-intuitive. :(

Comment: Do not know the answer in any authoritative level which is why I am only commenting. It would make sense for this to be possible at DB level since they already offer it as a filter. I'd look into how one can add a 'field' column in a query, a computed field. Otherwise you do have this door open at API level.

Comment: @Btdev did you ever find a solution? I've just come across this too